# Run $watch after custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing a custom directive to validate some value in the scope. It should work like the required attribute, but instead of validating the input text, it's going to validate a value in the scope. My problem is that this value is set in a $scope.$watch function and this function runs after my directive. So when my directive tries to validate the value it has not been set yet. Is it possible to run the $watch code before running my custom directive?

Here is the code:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var keys = {
    a: {},
    b: {}
  };
  $scope.data = {};

  // I need to execute this before the directive below
  $scope.$watch('data.objectId', function(newValue) {
    $scope.data.object = keys[newValue];
  });
});

app.directive('requiredAttribute', function (){ 
   return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
          var requiredAttribute = attr.requiredAttribute;
          ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
             ngModel.$setValidity('requiredAttribute', scope[attr.requiredAttribute] != null);
             return value;
          });
      }
   };
});

<input type="text" name="objectId" ng-model="data.objectId" required-attribute="object" />
<span class="invalid" ng-show="myForm.objectId.$error.requiredAttribute">Key "{{data.objectId}}" not found</span>
```

And here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/S2NrYj2AbxPqDrl5C8kQ?p=preview

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule the `$watch` to happen before the directive link function directly. You need to change your `link` function.

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
    var unwatch = scope.$watch(attr.requiredAttribute, function(requiredAttrValue) {
        if (requiredAttribute=== undefined) return;

        unwatch();

        ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
            ngModel.$setValidity('requiredAttribute', requiredAttrValue != null);
            return value;
        });
    });
}
```

This approach will activate the $watch function inside the directive only once and will remove the watcher the first time your required scope variable is set.

There is also another approach where you parse the value and check it this way:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
    var parsedAttr = $parse(attr.requiredAttribute);

    ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
        ngModel.$setValidity('requiredAttribute', parsedAttr(scope) != null);
        return value;
    });
}
```

Here you will need to use [$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse) AngularJS service. The difference here is that this will mark the input field as invalid without waiting for first value set on the required scope variable.

Both variants allow you to pass an expression instead of a simple variable name. This makes it possible to write something as `required-attribute="object.var1.var2"`.

It really depends on what you need.